# How to wrap each element of a list with no parameter lambda functions?

Tags: python, lambda

Given a list **A** of any objects, I want to create another list **B** of lambda functions, where each **B[i] ()** returns **A[i]**. For example,

```
B = [lambda: A[0], lambda: A[1], lambda: A[2], ...]
```

How can I do with for any arbitrary lengthed array **A**? Obviously, B = `[lambda: element for element in A]` does not work. What is a workaround for this?

Comment: It is, in fact, a duplicate of late binding question. You can force early binding by something like this: `B = [lambda element=element: element for element in A]`.

Comment: Should `B[i]()` be the value of `A[i]` at the time `B` was created or at the time `B[i]` was called?